# Manipulating problem for Lambert w function (Finding roots of equation)

Tags: logarithms, roots, graphing-functions, lambert-w

In my calculus book, a problem is to graph $y = x^3/24-\ln x$. One part of it was to find the roots of the equation. I was unable to do anything to solve this problem, and wolfram alpha used the Lambert w function. I searched it up, and what I could understand was that it's the inverse of $f(x) = xe^x$. 
However, I don't understand how I can manipulate this equation to get an answer. I was unable to find anything that had an answer. How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm sure your calculus book doesn't expect you to be familiar with Lambert W. Just to make sure: we're talking about $(x^3/24)-\log x$ here, not $x^3/(24-\log x)$, right?

Comment: Yep @GerryMyerson I'm pretty confused myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
y=x^3/24-\log\left(x\right)\tag1
$$
$$
-\frac18e^{-3y}=-\frac{x^3}8e^{-x^3/8}\tag2
$$
$$
\operatorname{W}\!\left(-\frac18e^{-3y}\right)=-\frac{x^3}8\tag3
$$
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{-2\operatorname{W}\!\left(-\frac18e^{-3y}\right)^{\!1/3}=x}\tag4
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: multiply both sides by $-3$, exponentiate, multiply both sides by $-\frac18$.
$(3)$: apply LambertW to both sides
$(4)$: take the cube root and multiply by $-2$

Note that for negative arguments, there are two branches of LambertW. For example, for $y=0$, the two branches give
$$
x=1.0493180227889868869
$$
and
$$
x=2.9660424669277519890
$$
which I computed in Mathematica as

`N[2(-LambertW[0,-1/8])^(1/3),20]`

and

`N[2(-LambertW[-1,-1/8])^(1/3),20]`

Answer (score 1):

I think the Lambert W Function might be a outside the scope of most calculus courses, although admittedly I hadn't heard of it before seeing this post so I don't know for sure. One thing you could try is using Newton's method or your calculator's graphing utility to approximate the zeros of $\frac{x^{3}}{24} - \ln(x)$. I doubt that there is a way to find exact expressions for the solutions to equations like that, at least not with techniques that I'm familiar with.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll just use Wolfram to approximate it. Hopefully my teacher doesn't expect us to solve it. Thanks.